# I don't know why my jqGrid subgrid doesn't show me the data

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid

I have problem with my subgrid data when I use [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) to program with my father. We do a grid with a subgrid; this receives JSON and PHP responses. We see it in the depuring of Mozilla and the syntax of the JavaScript code. Is it OK, not a problem of syntax or semantics?

Well, this is [my page](http://www.droguerialitoral.com.ar/Development/facturas.php) and my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divFacturas").html("<table><tr><td><table id='grillaFac' name='grillaFac' style=' height=2500px width=100%'></table> <DIV id='pggrillaFac' name='pggrillaFac'></DIV></td></tr></table>");
    var usuario = $("#usuario").val();
    var clave   = $("#clave").val();
    creaGrillaFacturas(usuario, clave);

    function creaGrillaFacturas(usuario, clave) {
        jQuery("#grillaFac").jqGrid(
        {
            url:'ajaxFacturas.php?usuario=' + usuario + '&clave=' + clave,
            datatype: "json",
            colNames:['Codigo', 'Tipo', 'Fecha/hora Comprobante', 'Comprobante', 'Debito', 'Credito', 'Resumen'],
            colModel:[ { name:'codigo', index:'codigo', width: 80, sorttype:'int'},
                       { name:'tipo', index:'tipo'},
                       { name:'fecha', index:'fecha'},
                       { name:'numero', index:'numero'},
                       { name:'debito', index:'debito', align: 'right', formatter:"number", summaryType:'sum' },
                       { name:'credito', index:'credito', align: 'right', formatter:"number", summaryType:'sum' },
                       { name:'resumen', index:'resumen', align: 'right'}
                     ],
            rowNum: 1000,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            forceFit:true,
            loadtext: 'Cargando',
            //loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            pager: '#pggrilla',
            altRows: true,
            sortname: 'codigo',
            sortorder: "desc",
            forceFit : true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            caption:"Comprobantes encontrados",
            //jsonReader: { repeatitems : false, id: 'codigo',
            //subgrid: {root: "rows", repeatitems: false}},
            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: 'codigo'},
            grouping : true,
            groupingView : { groupField: ['resumen'],
                             groupSummary: [true],
                             groupColumnShow: [true],
                             groupText: ['<b>Resumen Nro.: {0}</b>'],
                             groupCollapse: false,
                             groupOrder: ['desc']},
            subGrid: true,
            subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
                var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
                subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
                pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
                $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                    url:"subgrid.php?q=1162&id="+row_id,
                    dataype:"json",
                    colNames: ['Articulos', 'Descripcion', 'Cantidad', 'Precio unitario'],
                    colModel:[
                        {name:"articulo", index:"articulo", width:100},
                        {name:"detalle", index:"detalle", width:100},
                        {name:"cantidad", index:"cantidad", width:100},
                        {name:"precio", index:"precio", width:100}
                    ],
                    rowNum:20,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    //pager: pager_id,
                    sortname:'articulo',
                    sortorder:"asc",
                    height: '100%'
                });
                //jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{edit:false,add:false,del:false})
            }
        });

        jQuery("#grillaFac").jqGrid('hideCol', ['codigo']);
        jQuery("#grillaFac").jqGrid('navGrid', 'pggrillaFac',
               {search:true, edit:false, add:false, del:false});

        $("#grillaFac").setGridWidth($(window).width()-50);
        $("#grillaFac").setGridHeight($(window).height()-50);
    }
});
```

I hope you can help me :D.

Comment: Do you mean the SSH client PuTTY, meaning you are SSHing into a remote computer to work, or are you referring to something else?

Comment: SSH client PuTTY yep, i use to edit in the server i think..

Comment: Yeah, you probably use it to connect to the server where you do the work... ok, I just wondered if there was maybe a JS library called putty or something. Hmmmm, one other thing I'm wondering is when you wrote 'depuring' did you mean to write another word. If so which word?

Comment: sorry is not depuring, PuTTY have a option to monitor the syntax and semantics of language. And is everything ok. i dont know with its no showing data

Comment: Since the data for your subgrid is not paged try adding loadonce:true to the subgrid options and see what happens.

Comment: @AmeteGirl noup i tried and nothing.. i dont know what happend

Comment: Firebook on mozilla show the data good but grid no

Comment: Can  you add page and records to the subgrid json so it looks as {"page":"1","records":"1000", "rows":[{"articulo":"38420","detalle":"DESOD.REXONA ANT.F\/M HOMBRE X150ML.               ","cantidad":"2","precio":"43.20"}]}

Comment: @AmeteGirl no I add and nothing

Comment: This is so strange may be @Oleg could answer it.

Comment: @Oleg pls lol.. Or another option of sub grid i think

Comment: The jqgrid version you are using is older Try using the version of jqGrid Oleg forked at https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid and also remove one of  <script src="jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in your html. It is included twice which may cause incorrect behaviour.

Comment: I read the text of the question and the comments, but I still don't full understand the problem. Which web browser you use? Which version of jqGrid you use? What is not working? Do you tried to use Developer Tools of Internet Explorer or Chrome or to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to make HTTP trace? You write just "subgrid doesn't show me the data". It could be many reasons of the problem. The first thing which one can do to debug the code and to see whether subgrid will be created and the correct request to `subgrid.php?q=1162&id=...` will be sent.

Comment: There are some common things which can be improved in the code, but I suggest to start with the main problem. By the way it could be helpful to know **how many total rows are in the grid and how many rows are in Subgrid**. If you need to display less then 1000 or 10000 rows then the `loadonce: true` scenario could be the best choice in the final solution. One could report *full data for the grid and the subgrids* for all rows at once. If the total number of the items are not so large then you could create in the way the mostly responsive grid. **Some test JSON data would be very helpful too.**

Comment: @Oleg I debugged in his site in [Main Page](http://www.droguerialitoral.com.ar/Development/facturas.php) and I see the on subgridrowexpanded he gets the subgrid data correctly and the columns names are correct and json looks correct. Here is the data he gets in [Here](http://www.droguerialitoral.com.ar/Development/subgrid.php?q=1162&id=12076919&_search=false&nd=1462370482662&rows=20&page=1&sidx=articulo&sord=asc) and [Here](http://www.droguerialitoral.com.ar/Development/subgrid.php?q=1162&id=12173615&_search=false&nd=1462370451479&rows=20&page=1&sidx=articulo&sord=asc)

Comment: The subgrid URL returns `{"rows":false}` for the most sumbrids, but I could see one subgrid which seems to rerurn correct data from the server, which will be not displayed. I'd recommend you **don't use retro versions of jqGrid**. You use currently jqGrid 4.4.1 which is 4 years old. It corresponds driving the auto which is 40 years old. Why you do this? I strictly recommend you just change URLs to jqGrid files to URLs of free jqGrid 4.13.2 which you find [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) and to use `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` instead of `min`.

Comment: I recommend you to add additionally `idPrefix: subgrid_id` or `idPrefix: "s_" + row_id + "_"` as additional parameter of the subgrid, add `key: true` property to `articulo` column, remove all `index` properties from all items of the `colModel`, **change `dataype:"json"` to `datatype:"json"`** (one character is missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important bug in your code is the typing error: you use `dataype:"json"` instead of `datatype:"json"` as the option of subgrid. The unknown option `dataype` will be ignored and the default value `"xml"` of the option `datatype` will be used. The server returns JSON data and jqGrid will try to parse the data as XML data.

I recommend you don't use retro versions of jqGrid. You use currently jqGrid 4.4.1, which is 4 years old. It corresponds driving the auto which is 40 years old. I recommend you to use free jqGrid 4.13.2 and load it directly from the CDN. You need just modify the URLs to jqGrid files to URLs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).

Additionally it would be important to add `idPrefix` option to subgrid and use some *unique* value as the prefix. For example you can use `idPrefix: "s_" + row_id + "_"` or `idPrefix: subgrid_id` or just `idPrefix: $.jgrid.randId()`. Adding of `key: true` in the `articulo` column seems be good too.

Comment: Thx so much, i have to change the version of the jqGrid and add the character. You save my salary of the month :D

Comment: @tzanuttini: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you. I recommend you to add Font Awesome and to add `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option to jqGrid to improve the look of the grid. See [the example](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data_code) from the preliminary documentation and [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki). Many other new features which I implemented in free jqGrid are described in the READMEs to every published version and in the wiki.